# icCube reporting custom widget rendering when no data

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I created a new widget in icCube, working as desired when there is data...
But when the underlying MDX returns no data, I need to tell it to the user or to show something else...

How can I catch the fact that the MDX is in error or that it does not return any value?

Comment: It's currently not possible unless you 'hack' the widget. We'll keep this in mind for the upcoming version

Comment: Good to read this could be possible in future versions... In the meantime, how would you 'hack' the widget ?

Comment: Changing directly the code of the widget, it's the advantage of Javascript.